# Font icon show on localhost but when uploading on online it is not showing

Tags: html, css, fonts

We are designing a web font for **google fonts**. Our icon character is showing on **localhost**, but when uploading this file on a Linux server, the icon is not rendered.

When I inspect, the website is showing me some warning.

I post my **CSS** and **HTML** files:

**master.css**

```
/* FONTS*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i|Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i|Montserrat:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i|Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext');
@import '../fonts/fontawesome-free-5.6.1/css/all.min.css';
@import '../fonts/stroke/style.css';
@import '../fonts/elegant/style.css';
@import '../fonts/pe-icon-7-stroke/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css';
@import '../fonts/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css';
@import '../fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css';


/* PLUGIN CSS */

@import '../libs/bootstrap-4.1.3/bootstrap.css';                /* bootstrap */
@import '../plugins/headers/header.css';                /* header */
@import '../plugins/headers/yamm.css';                /* header */
@import '../plugins/slider-pro/slider-pro.css';         /* main slider */
@import '../plugins/slick/slick.css';         /* sliders */
@import '../plugins/slick/slick-theme.css';         /* sliders */
@import '../plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css';            /* modal */
@import '../plugins/animate/animate.css';                        /* animations */
@import '../plugins/flowplayer/skin/playful.css';          /* video-player */
@import '../plugins/noUiSlider/nouislider.css';          /* slider number */
@import '../plugins/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.min.css';                /* bootstrap-select */



/* MAIN CSS */

@import 'main.css';
@import 'color.css';
@import 'responsive.css';
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Home | Etgo</title>
    <meta content="Etgo" name="description">
    <meta content="Etgo" name="keywords">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <meta name="Etgo" content="true">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets\css\master.css">


    <!-- SWITCHER-->
    <!-- 
    <link href="assets\plugins\switcher\css\switcher.css" rel="stylesheet" id="switcher-css">
    <link href="assets\plugins\switcher\css\color1.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="color1">
    <link href="assets\plugins\switcher\css\color2.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="color2">
    <link href="assets\plugins\switcher\css\color3.css" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="color3">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
     -->


     <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.png">


    <!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
<script src="/assets/js/separate-js/html5shiv-3.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><meta content="no" http-equiv="imagetoolbar">
<![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
               .element {display:none;}

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .element{ display: inline;}
        .element2{ display: none;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

**Warning**

> ```
> Failed to decode downloaded font: https://etgocorp.in/website/assets/fonts/simple-line-icons/fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.txt
> index.html:1 OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT
> index.html:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://etgocorp.in/website/assets/fonts/flaticon/font/Flaticon.txt
> index.html:1 OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
> index.html:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: https://etgocorp.in/website/assets/fonts/fontawesome-free-5.6.1/webfonts/fa-brands-400.txt
> index.html:1 OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT
> ```

[image: Warning image]

[image]

Please understand my English is a little weak.

Thanks,

Comment: There seem to be issues with loading your fonts, oddly enough they are loaded as .txt which is kinda weird, but the path is ok. I always convert all of my fonts using [Transfonter](https://transfonter.org/) which avoids a lot of hassle.

Comment: @Adrenaxus :  I solved my problem because I was not proper uploading file on the server side so then I uploading through cpanel. Thank you for your response, and you also can check my post answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we uploaded font file through FTP It's not corrected uploaded; so
Sometimes is the FTP client that corrupt the file. So we font file uploaded to the cpanel through.

And we get the solution.

Thank you for your helpful response

Answer (score 0):

It would be for the best when you would download it and upload it aswell on linux server.

And I see that you're getting error message "Failed to decode downloaded font" and file has .txt in it. - Maybe there is something wrong with the link? Double check the link yourself.

Plus I don't see you importing any of those styles in index.html, try downloading font and uploading it on server.

Comment: all font are downloaded and nothing any css include on index page.

Comment: Yeah, but did you upload the fonts on server too? Because if they are saved locally, it wont load it on your server.

Comment: Have you updated the links exactly like in css file? And by that I mean on url(assets/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css). For HTML files that loads from server it should be for example, you have a folder named html and inside that folder another folder named css in which you have your stylesheet.css, so the url would be(/html/css/stylesheet.cs) and not (html/css/stylesheet.css). Please check if you've made a mistake.

Comment: index.html file are change please check

Comment: So, is your master.css in folder css on server? Is folder css in folder assets on server? If yes, try following: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/master.css"> (*Notice a slash before folder? That slash means that *folder is located at the root of the current web)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194809/discussion-between-save-and-asobak).